# Azure premium Storage and SQL Server Files

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-storage

I’m actually trying to use a Premium Storage to store SQL files like I usually do with classic storage: 
•   Generate a Shared Access Signature on Azure Storage Explorer 
•   Create credential on SQL server
•   Run some script like:

```
CREATE DATABASE HammerCont  
ON 
(NAME = HammerCont, 
   FILENAME = 'https://scopitpremiu.blob.core.windows.net/bdd/HammerCont.mdf') 
 LOG ON 
(NAME = HammerCont_log, 
    FILENAME = 'https://scopitpremiu.blob.core.windows.net/bdd/HammerCont.ldf')
```

But if it work fine with Standard-GRS storage, I still have this message « CREATE FILE encountered operating system error 1117(The request could not be performed because of an I/O device error.) while attempting to open or create the physical file 'https://scopitpremiu.blob.core.windows.net/bdd/HammerCont.mdf'. » on Premium-LRS storage.

Did I miss some prerequisites with premium storage?

Comment: Don't think so, it's a page blob :  Using this new feature, you can configure SQL Server so that any CREATE DATABASE statement will default to a cloud enabled database. In other words, you can set default data and log locations in SQL Server Management Studio Server instance properties so anytime you create a database, all database files (.mdf, .ldf) are created as page blobs in Windows Azure Storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently not supported in SQL Server. SQL Server will be releasing a hotfix in June to add support for creating data files on Azure Premium Storage.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, this information was not easy to find ! :) Can't wait to use this feature

Comment: We are in july and i still not be able to create database in premium storage, any news ?